# How to calculate limit of series using calculus

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

I have problem with calculating this limit, I know i should transform it into some integral but I don't know how:

> $$
> \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum _{ k=0 }^{ n } (-1)^{ k }\binom nk\frac { f\left( \frac { k }{ n }  \right)  }{ 2^{ n } }  } 
> $$

Comment: Do you have some information about $f$?

Comment: Ignore my last (deleted) comment: OP changed the post considerably

Comment: This will probably yield $0$ for a large subset of functions $f$. Some conditions would be nice though

Comment: Tell us what $f$ is, where it's defined, etc.

Comment: f is not defined by any formula , i guess all we can do is to assume it's integrable

Comment: Possible avenue of approach: use the identity $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{2^n}}\right)+\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{\binom{n}{k}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{2^n}}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\
k\text{ even}}}^n{\frac{2\binom{n}{k}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{2^n}}}$.

Comment: Then show the second term is twice the third term in the large-n limit.  Then imitate Bernstein's proof of Stone-Weierstrass somehow on that limit instead?

Comment: In particular, anytime I see $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$, I think of a Bernoulli trial.  It looks like you are playing a game with "payoff" $f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ and you want to apply a law of large numbers.